# How to indent entire strings of text in text file?

Tags: python, text-files

I have a dictionary:

```
page_info = {'LISTS':['string 1', 'string 2']}
```

I want to print to a text file with the word 'LISTS' being the header and values of key appearing below it and indented one space to the right.

```
with codecs.open(stats_file, 'a', encoding="utf8") as file:
    file.write('LISTS:' + '\n')
    for tag in page_info['LISTS']:
        file.write('\t' + tag + '\n\n')
```

Here's output to the file:
[image]

As you see, only the first line is indented for each string. How would I indent the entire block of text for a string?

Comment: you'd need to split each of those strings into their own lines, and indent each one. since you're dealing with only the string as a whole, you never do anything about the internal line breaks, only the very first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`textwrap` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) to wrap your lines and add indentation to each line:

```
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(initial_indent='\t', subsequent_indent='\t')
for tag in page_info['LISTS']:
    wrapped = wrapper.fill(tag)
    file.write(wrapped + '\n')
```

You may want to specify a `width` argument too; the default is set to 70 characters.